# Error on Di compile magento 2

Tags: magento2, controllers, unit-tests

I have set up Magento 2.4.4.

On di:compile I am getting this error.

Class "Hybrid_Provider_Model_OAuth2" not found#0 /var/www/vhosts/any.com/dev2.any.com/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(571)

I have found the issue, we have Ecomteck/OneStepCheckout in use which also uses Ecomteck/SocialLogin .

This social login module has a dependency of a library called "

hybridauth/hybridauth".

In Ecomteck/SocialLogin module the class uses **"/Hybrid_Provider_Model_OAuth2"** this is causing the issue.

any thoughts how to fix it ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: i'm not sure that running test on a controller rendering a webpage makes any sense. Unit tests would be more like for real methods. (Just my opinion). That being said, you need 2 things ; 1 - To know what you want to test exactly. 2 - To get Php unit. For a controller for example i would do something like that to ensure the link is working `        $client = static::createClient();
        $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());`

Comment: Hello @Claims, I am trying to create a test for the execute method.
Is there any way it can be done?
Can you help writing one ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Testing if the execute went fine is testing if by calling the url you are getting a 200 status code (In that specific case). Which is like the piece of code i mentionned above (though i don't really know how the client is defined in magento i never ran test on this framework; but what is behind is PhpUnit so i guess there might be a way to get the status code result. May be more something like `$this->getRequest()` would give you better information. I don't have any solution all done sry. Hoping sometone can help you better :) Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed info.

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run this command
`composer require hybridauth/hybridauth:2.18.0`
and then run magento setup upgrade commands

`php bin\magento setup:upgrade`

`php bin\magento setup:di:compile`

Comment: Let me test it.

Comment: Thank you, it worked but now it shows class "GeoIp2\Database\Reader" not found.

Comment: GeoIp2 is not part of Social login modules, I'm sure that this error came from another module, Anyway you can run this command ```` composer require geoip2/geoip2 ```` to add GeoIp2 to your project, you can also read more about GeoIp2 https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-php
If the main issue has been solved, please don't forget to mark this answer as correct